# Moving textfield up with keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this layout shown in the picture below:

[image]

I have this code to move the `Email Address` textfield up when the keyboard pops up:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    textfield1.frame = CGRectMake(textfield1.frame.origin.x, (textfield1.frame.origin.y - 100.0), textfield1.frame.size.width, textfield1.frame.size.height);
            [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

The only problem is when I move the textfield up like this it covers the `Email Login / Sign Up` Label right above it. Is there any way I can move the `Email Address` textfield up without covering that label? Or do I have to move every single view (such as the label) that is above that `Email Address` textfield up as well?

Comment: You should review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider observing the system notifications:

- `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`
- `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`
- `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`
- `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification`

And check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/UIKeyboardWillShowNotification)

You should move the view that wraps all the `UITextField`s (if no such view, just create a "form view" containing those fields). The `userInfo` property of the notification object contains the size of the keyboard. You can use that information and position the form view with a distance from the keyboard frame.

Comment: Yeah I think I will have to create a separate view containing the required text fields to sign up. Thanks.

Comment: sorry my friend, you should leave the original question as is, and ask a new question. You can see now that the question and the accepted answer become irrelevant.

Comment: Ok sure. I will create a new question!

Answer (score 0):

First You have to add keyboard notification observer "UIKeyboardWillShowNotification" in your viewDidLoad or any other initialiser method as:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

Then define the method "keyboardWillShow:" in your view controller class as:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
   CGFloat _currentKeyboardHeight = kbSize.height;
}
```

Now you will get Keyboard height value. Based on this value You can adjust your textfield's 'y' position.

Comment: But if I do this and adjust my textfield's `y` position, then it will go up and cover the `Email Login / Sign Up` Label right above it.

Comment: Instead try moving your view by currentKeyboardHeight value which you get from this method  :[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -currentKeyboardHeight ,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what I did as well and it glitched up. Also just a side question, is it better to move the entire view up or just have a scrollview to do this job?

Comment: I believe using a UIScrollView in this scenario will be an unnecessary work, when we can animate and move the position of the frame of the view easily.

Comment: Addition to above information, don't forget to remove your notification observer once you are out of the view. That is, add this line: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];   in viewWillDisappear or dealloc method.

Answer (score 0):

Add scrollview as subview to existing View and then place all controls on this subview.

Use below code for smooth keyboard push while text editing.

```
//Declare in implementation file

static const CGFloat KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3;
static const CGFloat MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.2;
static const CGFloat MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.8;
static const CGFloat PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 216;

//static const CGFloat LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 162;


#pragma - UITextField Delegates
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    //Perform Animation during Keyboard show and Hide
    CGRect textFieldRect = [self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
    CGRect viewRect = [self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];

    CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
    CGFloat numerator = midline - viewRect.origin.y - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;

    CGFloat denominator = (MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION) * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;

    if (heightFraction < 0.0) {
        heightFraction = 0.0;
    }
    else if (heightFraction > 1.0) {
        heightFraction = 1.0;
    }

    animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);

    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Refer this [link.](http://jayprakashdubey.blogspot.in/2014/07/animate-scrollview-on-editing.html)

Comment: I actually previously did this. But I ran into the problem of setting proper auto layout constraints on the views inside of the scrollview. `Has ambious scorollable content width/height` Would this be a better way of doing it? This moves the entire view up or done: http://blog.koder.me/ios/2015/05/25/move-uitextfield-up-down-with-keyboard.html

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the above answers, have you considered using a **UIAlertController** instead?  These auto-format to be where you'd want them to be so that the user can always type without stuff being ugly (well, not always, but most of the time).  You can read more about implementation [here](https://www.invasivecode.com/weblog/uialertcontroller-alert-action-sheet/), but the general gist would be something like this:

```
UIAlertController* passAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Email Login/Sign Up" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[passAlert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField* textField) {
        textField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"username", @"username");
    }];
[passAlert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField* textField) {
        textField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"password", @"password");
    }];
UIAlertAction* doneAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction* action) {
        // do whatever you need to do to process the login and password
    }];

[passAlert addAction:doneAction];
```

In the interest of transparency, my deep wisdom and arcane knowledge of textfields in alerts comes from [here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/uialertcontroller-changes-in-ios-8/).

Very likely the other answers given are more useful for your case - you have a nice looking UI, a dope kind of Google Cards type thing, and I bet you don't want to give that sick look up.  But if you'd like a cool alternative, here's one that should work more consistently than most peoples' ad-hoc solutions :).

Comment: No that was still a very good suggestion! I never even thought of that way and will definitely try that out as well. Thanks man!